# Переход на другой View по NavigationLink SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

Возможно мой вопрос покажется глупым или простым, ведь я только учусь.

При переходе на новый вью через NavigationLink я хочу оставлять только иконку назад и вставлять новое название на вью

Вот пример как я хочу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]:

А вот что выходит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Первый вью:

```
struct NewLoanView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            VStack {
                
                NavigationLink(destination: CalculatorView()) {
                    Text("Оформить займ")
                }
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .background(Color.orange)
            }
            
            .navigationBarTitle("Мой займ")
        }
        
    }
}
```

Вот вью куда переходим:

```
struct CalculatorView: View {
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {

            .navigationTitle("Оформить займ")
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К сожалению, некоторые вещи совсем элегантно изменить не получится.

Шаг первый:

```
// Кастомная кнопка назад
struct CustomBackButton: View {
    let action: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: action) {
            Image(systemName: "arrow.backward")
                .foregroundColor(.green)
        }
    }
}
```

Шаг второй:

```
// Скрыть кнопку назад и использовать свою:
struct CalculatorView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello")
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            .navigationBarItems(leading: CustomBackButton {
                
            })
    }
}
```

Шаг третий:

```
// Событие "назад"
struct CalculatorView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode> // <---
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello")
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            .navigationBarItems(leading: CustomBackButton {
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() // <---
            })
    }
}
```

Результат:

[image: Example]

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Целый день изобретал костыли. Как по мне это элегантно)